# Finding performance-related release-only bugs in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, debugging

I am currently developing a project and I'm working in debug during development.

Typically, I'm just working in release mode before I am releasing the next update to check if everything works as expected.

During the last release tests, I found a bug that just appears in release mode.
As soon as I set the optimization level to 1 or higher (I'm using LLVM 4.2), the bug starts to appear.

I don't have any clue what the error could be related to.
Does anyone have an idea what I could do to find the reason of the error?
Instruments maybe? Didn't find a mode that would fit.

It's a performance-related error and I can't seem to find it with breakpoints.
My first guess is that the main thread is running full so that not all events can be processed in time.

If that was it, why would that not happen in debug mode?

Comment: I have a CoreMIDI thread telling some classes whenever a new MIDI timecode message is available using notifications. It gets called around every 40 ms. The timecode is controlling QuickTime movie playback. It seems that the notification handling is somehow queued as the QuickTime movie is not playing in sync with the incoming timecode. There's also an external graphics card supplied with the frames from the QT movie and there are also a lot of UI updates going on.

Comment: How are you handling QuickTime playback? The built-in QuickTime and QTKit objects won't give you accurate sync; you have to either (a) register a custom QT clock component to drive the playback, or (b) use VideoToolbox to handle decoding frames and buffer them yourself. If you're doing one of those, you may want to try adding `NSLog`s to check the timing of the quarter-frame messages being processed. Notifications may not be the most efficient way to process them, but that alone shouldn't be causing visible sync issues.